# CollectionView Cells are not visible

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

Using Swift 5.1.3, iOS13.3,

I am trying to display a horizontal CollectionViewController as a ChildView Controller.

The issue: All Cells are invisible !

The print-statement in the Code (shown with lots of !!!!!!!! in the comment below)

```
Test.CardHeaderCell: 0x7fa563709370; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1059 23; 343 279); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024de080>>
```

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...

    let cardsHorizontalController = CardsHorizontalController()
    self.addChild(cardsHorizontalController)
    self.view.addSubview(cardsHorizontalController.view)
    self.didMove(toParent: cardsHorizontalController)
    cardsHorizontalController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cardsHorizontalController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 70.0).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 390.0).isActive = true
    cardsHorizontalController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
}
```

Here is the HorizontalController

```
class CardsHorizontalController: HorizontalSnappingController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "horizontalCardID"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .green

        collectionView.register(CardHeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        }

        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        // do the insets here instead of the optional "insetForSectionAt" delegate-method
        // i.e. this helps to get the scrolled cells aligned in the middle of the screen once 1 cell wide scrolled...
        collectionView.contentInset = .init(top: 65.0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 16.0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: view.frame.width - 32.0, height: 279.0)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 17
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        print(cell)
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        return cell
    }

}
```

And the Cell:

```
class CardHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let imageView = UIImageView(cornerRadius: 10.0)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // blur view
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.086, green: 0.086, blue: 0.086, alpha: 0.35)
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: imageView.frame)
        visualEffectView.effect = UIView.customBlurEffect()
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth.rawValue | UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight.rawValue)
        imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

        let stackView = VerticalStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            imageView
        ], spacing: 12.0)
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.fillSuperview(padding: .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }   
}
```

And for completeness reasons, here the rest of the custom classes...

```
class HorizontalSnappingController: UICollectionViewController {

    init() {
        let layout = BetterSnappingLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

```
class BetterSnappingLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
        }

        let nextX: CGFloat

        if proposedContentOffset.x <= 0 || collectionView.contentOffset == proposedContentOffset {
            nextX = proposedContentOffset.x
        } else {
            nextX = collectionView.contentOffset.x + (velocity.x > 0 ? collectionView.bounds.size.width : -collectionView.bounds.size.width)
        }

        let targetRect = CGRect(x: nextX, y: 0, width: collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)

        var offsetAdjustment = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

        let horizontalOffset = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionView.contentInset.left

        let layoutAttributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: targetRect)

        layoutAttributesArray?.forEach({ (layoutAttributes) in
            let itemOffset = layoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
            if fabsf(Float(itemOffset - horizontalOffset)) < fabsf(Float(offsetAdjustment)) {
                offsetAdjustment = itemOffset - horizontalOffset
            }
        })

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x + offsetAdjustment, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

}
```

```
class VerticalStackView: UIStackView {

    init(arrangedSubviews: [UIView], spacing: CGFloat = 0, alignment: UIStackView.Alignment = .center) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        arrangedSubviews.forEach({addArrangedSubview($0)})

        self.spacing = spacing
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.axis = .vertical
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CardHeaderCell` and add cell item's in cell's contentView at `cellForRowAt` method

Comment: I did that just now. But no change. The cells are still invisible !

Comment: delegate and datasource of collectionView should be connected

Comment: @Kisham Bhatiya: Can you please be more specific on where (i.e. in which of my above classes) and how the delegates should be assigned ? I am working purely in code (no storyboard)

Comment: Try in first `viewDidLoad()` change `self.didMove(toParent: cardsHorizontalController)` to `cardsHorizontalController.didMove(toParent: self)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

The class `VerticalStackView` had a default Alignment property `.center`.

When I replace `.center` by `.fill` as a default value - then everything works as expected !

The usage of the VerticalStackView remains the same (i.e. default value for alignment applies):

```
let stackView = VerticalStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
    imageView
], spacing: 12.0)
```

[image]